# Why Will UITableView Background Color Not Change? (Xcode 7 beta 4)

Tags: uitableview

I am working in Interface Builder of Xcode 7 (beta 4) and I am modally presenting a `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableView`. The background of my view controller's `view` is clear because I am presenting it over the current context, and it contains a `UIVisualEffectView` with a dark blur so that the initial `UIViewController`'s content is slightly visible from underneath.

I am trying to get my table view to have a clear background with clear backgrounds on all of the cells so that the blur view is visible throughout the table, which I have successfully accomplished in Xcode 6. However, when trying to do the same exact thing in Xcode 7 (beta 4), this is what I am left with: [image]

The only property of the table view and cells that I have changed in Interface Builder is `backgroundColor`.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: I do not know what the problem is, but I'm having this exact same issue. In an old project, all my tableViews that used to be clear background are now for some reason white. Started on the beta4 as well

Comment: It looks like everyone has this problem on beta 4. A radar has been submitted: https://openradar.appspot.com/21947111

Answer (score 2):

I have found exactly the same bug. I can fix it by adding the below code into the viewDidLoad of the VC, but I am not going to go through every VC and do this until this is confirmed as a bug or new behaviour. Seems pointless to add code that doesn't need to be there if a bug fix is due. But for now:

```
[self.yourTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // XCode 7.0b4 bug. Not picking up from Storyboard
[self.yourTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]; // XCode 7.0b4 bug. Not picking up from Storyboard
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A work around that seems to be work for me is to set the background to `.clearColor()` programmatically instead of in the storyboard

Comment: Your solution works for the table view, however, it is not working for the cells of the table. Have you ran into this issue? I placed ```cell.backgroundColor = .clearColor()``` and ```cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()``` in ```cellForRowAtIndexPath:``` with no avail. The background of the cells are still showing up as a light grayish color as in my attached photo from the original post, which is weird in itself because they should be the same color as the table view's ```backgroundColor```.